# How can we call another activity by using fragment tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment, android-dialogfragment

I am using fragment with tabs, and i use listfragment in tab,i want to go another acitivity on item clicklistner, i am using below code:

```
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        Intent i = new Intent(activity, Motherboard.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

it is going to another activity but it not showing tabbars.
I want if any activity call then the tabbar remain infront.
Please help me out.

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might helps you

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/

and to support in all versions you can use Action bar sherlock library which is also provided in that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments ate part of an activity. If you move to another activity and you want it to have fragments as well, you will have to create fragments in it. 
 Alternatively, you can remain in the same activity and just switch the fragment without starting a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create one BaseActivity with tabs like

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

}
```

and all other activities extends BaseActivity

**EDIT**

small example for you

BaseActivity.java

```
 abstract public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // add tabs to actionbar
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB 1")
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB 2")
            .setTabListener(this));

}

}
```

FirstActivity.java

```
   public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            tab.getText() + " selected in FirstActivity",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
    public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            tab.getText() + " selected in SectondActivity",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add/Replace Another fragment in the onclick method instead of starting another activity

Answer (score 0):

unless you do want to write a super-class that implements a tab-bar in all of your activities that inherit from this super-class, you can just try to replace your fragment with another fragment. Saves alot of memory aswell.