# Android reuseability of Button onClickListener

Tags: android

I am working on a Android project. Every page has a Footer(settings, My profile, Back Button ) ...I want to write this functionality(footer button click functionality) in BaseView so that i can extends this BaseView from my all other activity and also i no need to call this same functionality from every page. How can i implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try custom layout:

```
   public class Footer extends LinearLayout {

public Context context;
public ImageButton btnNearest, btnPin, btnRegister;

public Footer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    if (!isInEditMode())
        init();
}

private void init() {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.footer, this, true);
    btnNearest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_nearest_aed);
    btnPin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pin_aed);
    btnRegister = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_register_aed);
}

}
```

this is for all xml:

```
     <com.pkg.Footer
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in your base class that is of OnClickListenerType and put your common code there. Then you can set the onclick listener for each button in your child classes.

In your base class:

```
   OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

In your child class:

```
   button.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: post this a a comment not as a answer

Comment: @Gaurav - why should it be a comment?

Comment: Now you have updated your answer now it's fine

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've only recently started to be active here, still learning the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create one BaseActivity like

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

}
```

and all other activities extends BaseActivity

here is small [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272569/how-can-we-call-another-activity-by-using-fragment-tabs/18272833#18272833). It uses actionbar you have to change it for buttons.